# What does "joining it" mean?

Tags: meaning

> You can tick in an option to favorite the channel
>   **for the whole team and members joining it.**

What does the bold part mean? Does it mean "you can tick in an option to favorite the channel where the whole team and members are joining"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here for is used as preposition meaning **in order to help somebody** .

> You can tick in an option to favorite the channel for(in order to help the whole team and members joinng it) the whole team and members joining it.

**For** can also be used to mean **representing a group, country, organisation etc**

> You can tick in an option to favorite the channel for(you are representing the whole team ) the whole team and members joining it.

Comment: It depends on context which one is better used

Comment: In the second case, does it mean "the channel where the whole team and members joined"?

Comment: No channel can mean any channel like tv channel or any sports channel.

Comment: You(suppose jay) is representing the whole team

Comment: Doesn't the second usage of "for" mean "of"? If it doesn't mean "the channel of the whole team and members joining it", then what does it mean?

Comment: If I say I played for India in Olympics it means I represented India in Olympics